# What is wrong with this assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86

It says invalid combination of opcode and operands

```
section .data
    name:      db "What is your name?"
    name_L:     equ $-name
    hello:     db "Hello"
    hello_L:     equ $-hello
section .bss
    name_V     resb 255



section .test


    global _start:
_start:

    mov eax, 4
    mov eax, 1
    mov ecx, name
    mov edx, name_L
    int 80h
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, name_V
    mov edx, 255
    int 80h
    int eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, hello
    mov edx, hello_L
    int 80h
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, name_V
    mov edx, 255
    int 80h
    mov eax, 1
    mov eax, 0
    int 80h
```

Comment: Which line(s) does the assembler report as containing an error? And which assembler are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Well, normally, the assembler will actually *tell* you which line is the offending one, and you should examine the opcode and operands to ensure compatibility (or, at the very minimum, let *us* know which line it is).

In the meantime, you have either incorrect or superfluous code in your program just after `_start`:

```
mov eax, 4
mov eax, 1 ; probably should be ebx
```

If these are Linux calls, you're probably lucky it didn't assemble. Passing a random length to `sys_write` is going to cause all sorts of grief :-) Passing a random exit value to `sys_exit` is also not advised:

```
mov eax, 1
mov eax, 0 ; probably should be ebx
int 80h
```

And are you *certain* that you want the `text` (code) section to be called `test`?

You would also go a long way toward making your code readable by using `equ` values rather than magic numbers and adding comments:

```
fn_exit    equ 0
fb_read    equ 3
fn_write   equ 4
:
mov eax, fn_write      ; write 
mov ebx, 1             ;  to stdout (fd 1)
mov ecx, name          ;  text to write
mov edx, name_L        ;  length of text to write
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the other answers have covered, this line is incorrect:

```
int eax, 4
```

I'm assuming that it was supposed to be a `mov` instruction rather than `int`.

Comment: Damn I've missed that one! Nice! +1

Comment: Actually, this one is probably the winner. Giving eax as the operand to the int opcode is _definitely_ a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

I don't see `[BITS32]` directive in your code which might result in trying to load a 16bit offset into your 32bit registers if your assembler's default mode is 16bit

/EDIT

Comment: `mov ecx, name` is valid NASM syntax (which is what the OP appears to be using). It's equivalent to `mov ecx,OFFSET name` in MASM/TASM syntax.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! I wonder, however, what the root of problem might be in this case every other *opcode* usage is flawless. At `global _start:` I don't think the colon is necessary/legal and the assembler might as well be complaining about this fact, but there is definitely no *opcode* there. The code is straightforward so one could spot the mistake immediately if it was there, based on the error message. Maybe it's not the full source?

Comment: @Michael ...But nothing else seems to be logical for this simple code... Thanks btw. It's a really strange problem then. Looking forward for the solution.

Comment: @Michael AAAAAAAAAAAH isn't it that `[BITS32]` is missing???